# OpenCL log file locates errors as if the code was a single long line

Tags: c++, opencl

I produce a log file (with OpenCL on OSX) doing

```
void printErrors(const Program& program, const Device& device){
    string buildlog = program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(device);
    ofstream file("./error.txt");
    file << buildlog << endl;
    file.close();
}
```

But the resulting file seems to interpret the code as a single VERY long line. For example, an error is located as `<program source>:1:10604:`. Which is not very convenient for debugging. Do you know how to get a good location like `<program source>:line:column:` ?

By the way, for each error/warning the entire program is copied in the log file. Do you know how to avoid this behavior ?

The source code is generated this way:

```
ifstream file("./kernel.cl");

string source;

while (!file.eof()){
    char line[256];
    file.getline(line, 255);
    source += line;
}

const char* kernel_source = source.c_str();

program = Program(context, kernel_source);

int result = program.build(device);
if (result == CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE) printErrors(program, device);
```

And the file kernel.cl is really standard with semicolon at the end of each line.

Comment: How are you generating your source code? What characters actually separate lines? How are you passing the code to OpenCL? I didn't downvote your question, but you're not actually providing the code that allows us to reproduce the problem, so that may be a reason someone did.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I elaborated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is here:

```
char line[256];
file.getline(line, 255);
source += line;
```

`getline` will not include newline characters, so you will need to insert them explicitly. Try this:

```
source += line;
source += "\n";
```

This should also solve the issue of the entire source-on-one-line being included in the error message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I already tried but nothing changed.

Comment: Sorry for my first comment, I tried again and it works ! Thanks a lot @pmdj. And by the way you are true, it solved my second point !